# What's a good (and simple) way to push files to our production website?

Tags: git, publish, rsync, monorepo

Our website is under git for source control, and we used to be able to publish to our production website via a git push.  The server was a read-only remote.

Recently, we merged the website into a larger monorepo and had to abandon that method of updating the server.  I created a shell script which uses rsync to push it to the server, and (after adding an exclude file) it works.

The problem:  Because of timestamp differences, when different users run the script, the whole tree gets pushed up, even though 99.9% of the files are identical.

So what's a simple and efficient way to push changes to a website when the website is a subset of a git repository?  I looked at git subtrees and thought it was too complicated. Is there a way to use git to make a file list of what's changed and then use rsync to push only those files up to the server?

Comment: Isn’t there an option for rsync to skip files based on their content (ignoring timestamps)? You should post the exact rsync invocation you are using.

Comment: rsync -avH -e ssh --exclude-from=do_not_rsync . username@servername:rootdir

Comment: I'm not sure what the best method is for you, but I do know that using git as a distribution tool is a bad idea.

Comment: @mkrieger1 is correct.  The -c option will always compare with a checksum, and that should work for me.  Thanks!